# GitHubのフォルダが空になって表示されます

Tags: github, github-desktop

#### やりたいこと

ソースコードを管理したい

なぜうまくいかないのかわからないので教えていただきたいです。
初学者です。よろしくお願いします！

#### 前提条件

vue-calendar/
└─ backend/   # Railsのプロジェクト
└─ frontend/  # Vue.jsのプロジェクト

#### 発生まで実行したコマンド

Add　Existing Repository...

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

create a repository

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

history

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 発生したエラー

GitHb上

backend
frontend

```
The file is empty
```

Comment: backendとfrontendのディレクトリ以下にはファイルは置いてありますか？それとも空のディレクトリですか？

Comment: appなどrailsで扱うフォルダ、ファイルが一通りあります。

Comment: 「空になって表示される」までに GitHub に対して何らかの操作を行ったはずですが、その手順を質問に追記してみてください。

Comment: 色々触って一旦削除とかしたので、はっきり覚えてませんが、一応追加しました。

Comment: コミットやプッシュはしていないということですか？

Comment: 変更履歴がgithubに反映されず、コミットができません

Comment: 操作しているのは恐らく GitHub Desktop というクライアントですよね？表示されている画面で History タブを開くとどうなりますか？ (きちんとコミットが出来ているのか確認してください)

Answer (score 1):

スクリーンショットに書かれているメッセージを読む限り、そもそも GitHub に手元の環境をアップロードできていないようです。更にお手元の環境が Git でバージョン管理されていません。

まずはお手元の環境を Git でバージョン管理し、手元のファイルをコミットして、GitHub に git push するようにしてください。

Comment: github上で
①Add　Existing Repository...
②create a repository

を実施すると追加した画像のようになります。

Answer (score 1):

普通にプログラムを書いてビルドするときは、複数種類のファイルが生成されます。

- ソースファイル（人間が書くファイル `hoge.c` など）
- 中間ファイル（コンパイラ等が生成するファイル `hoge.o` など）
- 最終生成物（リンカ等で生成するファイル `hoge.exe` など）

ソースコード管理ツール (SCM) では上記のうちソースファイルだけを管理します。ソースファイルさえあれば中間ファイルや最終生成物はビルドすれば作れるからです。なので `git` をはじめ SCM を使い始める最初の手順は

- リポジトリを作る `git init` 等
- SCM で無視する中間ファイル名を「無視ファイル設定」に書く `.gitignore` 等
- ソースファイルだけを SCM に追加する `git add` 等

です。２番目以後がまるまる抜けているのでリポジトリは作っただけで内容が空です。その証拠に「変更内容が無い。非管理ファイルだけが存在している」という警告が出ています。なので最初にすべきは `git add` で、その際に「このファイルはソースファイル、このファイルは中間ファイル」みたいな判断を人間が行い `.gitignore` を記入する、という手順です。 let's try!

Answer (score 0):

恐らく操作しているのは **GitHub Desktop** というアプリであり、作業した内容を実際に登録するには「コミット」という作業が必要になります。

**参考:**
[プロジェクトへの変更のコミットやレビュー](https://docs.github.com/ja/desktop/contributing-and-collaborating-using-github-desktop/making-changes-in-a-branch/committing-and-reviewing-changes-to-your-project)

> [コミットメッセージの入力と変更のプッシュ](https://docs.github.com/ja/desktop/contributing-and-collaborating-using-github-desktop/making-changes-in-a-branch/committing-and-reviewing-changes-to-your-project#write-a-commit-message-and-push-your-changes)
>
> コミットに含めたい変更を決めたら、コミットメッセージを入力して変更をプッシュします。
>
> 1. 変更のリストの下のSummary（サマリー）フィールドに短く分かりやすいコミットメッセージを入力してください。
> 2. Description（説明）フィールドの下で、Commit to BRANCH（ブランチにコミット）をクリックしてください。

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございます！何度もすみません
質問の方にコミット時の画像追加しました。